# Testing Marionette application with Mocha and Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, mocha.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to test my application using Mocha and Zombie.js, but I'm getting an "Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded" when trying to load the page.

As I could see, it seems that the "Backbone.history.start();" is affecting it somehow and preventing Zombie.js to assert that the page has finished loading.

If I comment out the "Backbone.history.start();" line, my application will not start, but the Zombie.js will think that the page has finished loading.

The code below is an example of a code that is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="../public/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/vendor/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/vendor/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Application = new Marionette.Application();

      Application.on("initialize:after", function() {

        if (Backbone.history) {
          Backbone.history.start();
        }

        if (Backbone.history.fragment === "") {
          Backbone.history.navigate("something", {});
        }
      });

      Application.start();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Check the return value of Backbone.history.start ().  If it is false, try put in Marionette.AppRouter for Backbone.history to match a route, simple root route will be sufficient in this case.

Comment: I added a router to Marionette.AppRouter, so the Backbone.history.start() returns true, but that doesn't make any difference. It is still falling...

Comment: Investigating a little bit more, what I could see is that "onhashchange" is not available in the window object when the code is running on Zombie.js. At least, "('onhashchange' in window)" is false when running on Zombie.js.

Comment: The problem was related to window.onhashchange equals undefined instead of null when running the code on Zombie.
This was fixed on 2.0.0-alpha29.